# MVC5 - Create RDLC report via ASPX, View must derive from ViewPage error

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC5 project using VS2013, and tried to follow the 12 steps here to create a rdlc report.
http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/01/how-to-display-rdlc-report-in-report-viewer-control-into-mvc4.html

However, I kept getting this error at the partial view rendering.

```
The view must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.
```

I looked up all the similar articles, tried adding reference to System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage in web.config under View, via inheritance. Also tried adding IgnoreRoute in Global.asax/RouteConfig.cs.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```

Yet, I still received this error: (Any suggestions?)

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The view at '~/Views/Shared/RPT_Test_ASPX.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The view at '~/Views/Shared/RPT_Test_ASPX.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.

Source Error: 


Line 3:  }
Line 4:  <h2>My Test List</h2>
Line 5:  @Html.Partial("RPT_Test_ASPX")
Line 6:  
Line 7:  

Source File: c:\SVN\TestProject\trunk\TestProject\Views\Report\Index.cshtml    Line: 5 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The view at '~/Views/Shared/RPT_Test_ASPX.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.]
   System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +278
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) +467
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +155
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName) +91
   ASP._Page_Views_Report_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\SVN\TestProject\trunk\TestProject\Views\Report\Index.cshtml:5
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +270
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +122
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +63
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +100
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +131
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +695
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9644097
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer here:
https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started

Basically, install ReportViewerForMvc via NuGet,

```
PM> Install-Package ReportViewerForMvc
```

and it will put a "ReportViewerWebForm.aspx" page at the root of your project. Do all your rdlc & data source mapping in your controller, place it in the ViewBag, and call the View.

In the View (cshtml) page, add

```
@using ReportViewerForMvc
```

on top, and add this viewer in the body.

```
@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
```

It works for me. Hope this helps others.

---

Here's my controller code:

```
MyEntities context = new MyEntities();
var myData = context.usp_MyStorProc(_var1, _var2);

ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();

reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath);

reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportDataSource rdc = new ReportDataSource("MyDataSourceName", myData);

reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdc);
reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath += @"Reports/MyReportName.rdlc";
reportViewer.Width = 900;
reportViewer.Height = 600;
reportViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.PageWidth;

ViewBag.MyReportName = reportViewer;
```

---

Be sure to include all the ReportViewer references (which can be found in GAC or download from Microsoft's website):

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms